# Google Drive Api for Service account. Error while creating a file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, jwt

I've created a folder and a file with permission to access a file for any Internet user. I used to think upload itself worked properly. Unfortunately, when I use

> [https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={file.id}](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=%7Bfile.id%7D)

command, all I see is a black square and when I trying to download via download link file's property, it even couldn't be opened.

So, here's my code

```
private static String initiateResumable(string base64, string fileType){
    String endpoint ='https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable';

    map<String, Object> md = new map<String, Object>();

    md.put('name', 'demofile'); 
    md.put('parents', '[' + folderId + ']'); 

    String metadata = JSON.serialize(md);

    Integer size = Math.min(2000000, base64.length());

//return an HttpRequest object of POST method with
// Authorization token provided (JWT is used)
    HttpRequest req = createRequest('post');

    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(metadata.length()));
    req.setHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', fileType);
    req.setHeader('X-Upload-Content-Length', String.valueOf(size));

    req.setBody(metadata);

    HttpResponse res = (new Http()).send(req);

    return res.getHeader('Location');
}

private static File sendFile(String base64, String fileType, String endpoint){
    Integer size = Math.min(2000000, base64.length());
    HttpRequest req = createRequest('put');
    HttpResponse res;

    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

    req.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType);

    while(! String.isBlank(base64)){
        final string buffer = base64.left(size);
        base64 = base64.removeStart(buffer);

        req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(buffer.length()));
        req.setBody(buffer);

        res = (new Http()).send(req);
    }

    return (File)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), File.class);
}
```

I believe that's because of base64 format, but I may be wrong

The same error occurs with the following code:

```
    HttpRequest req = createRequest('get');
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media');
            
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueOf(base64.length()));
    req.setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64');
    
    req.setBody(base64);
    
    HttpResponse res = (new Http()).send(req);
    
    File file = (File) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), File.class);
    
    return file;
```

It's Salesforce's Apex so no way for any frameworks, but the syntax is quite straightforward, I believe.

Comment: Could you share any errors from your logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors. Meant to say, that's told by google drive API dashboard. Moreover, the file created could be retrieved via '/files' and '/files/fileId' HTTP requests both

Comment: Probably, it could be useful. That's an Id of a file creted: 19FHn4Lxke_10exvF-C0Z4OjI3pnr77I0

It's downloadURL: https://doc-08-0o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/jcu7h6n32m8gjvolo86acn0b3n6vaj7g/rvbha4q4aggmqp62i3kkpqcjvtjqte3r/1551952800000/12497135298679427241/12497135298679427241/19FHn4Lxke_10exvF-C0Z4OjI3pnr77I0?e=download&gd=true

And embedURL : https://drive.google.com/file/d/19FHn4Lxke_10exvF-C0Z4OjI3pnr77I0/preview?usp=drivesdk